Какой псевдокласс использовать
У меня есть собственный класс кнопки в css, я его использую для того, чтобы была кнопка в radio field
<div class="btn-group">
    <input class="form-check-input btn-check" type="radio" name="quest{{i}}" id="{{i}}answer-1">
    <label class="btn btn-succses" style="width: 100%" for="{{i}}answer-1">{{quest.answer1}}</label>
    <input class="form-check-input btn-check" type="radio" name="quest{{i}}" id="{{i}}answer-2">
    <label class="btn btn-primary" style="width: 100%" for="{{i}}answer-2">{{quest.answer2}}</label>
</div>

я пытаюсь в css файле изменить псевдокласс, чтобы когда кнопка активна у нее менялся bg
*.btn.btn-succses {
  background-color: #e2ee83;
  border: 3px solid #bfd833;
  font-family:cursive;
  border-radius: 4px;}

*.btn.btn-succses:hover {
  background-color: #bfd833;
  border: 3px dashed #a2b827;}

*.btn.btn-succses:active {
  background-color: #bfd833!important;
  border: 3px dashed #a2b827!important;}

но это не помогает и ничего не меняется. Подскажите пожалуйста что нужно использовать

Что конкретно такое «когда кнопка активна»? Каковы ваши критерии «активности»?

Я использую кнопки в качестве label для radio input. И для меня критерий активности это когда кнопка была нажата. На bootstrap https://getbootstrap.ru/docs/5.3/forms/checks-radios/

По критерию «когда кнопка была нажата» здесь всё замечательно работает. Из-за того, что вы написали одинаковые стили для :hover и :active, это не заметно, но если убрать hover, то становится видно, что нажатие действительно меняет стиль — https://i.sstatic.net/pzuYI.gif

вы немного не понимаете, прочтите статью на бутстрап и поймете что у меня не так, кнопка является неким чекбоксом. которая после нажатия является активной. об этом написано на бутстрапе.

была нажата и является нажатой немного разные вещи

*.btn-group>.btn-check:checked+.btn-succses{background-color: #c583ee; }
я нашел решение

*.btn-group>.btn-check:checked+.btn-succses{
    background-color: #c583ee;
}


это ответ или дополнение к вопросу?

Добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! Пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять более развёрнутые ответы. Дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit].
